# Change alarm time set in clock app

Tags: java, android

I want my app to be able to change the alarm time which got set by another app (like the clock app).
So if the alarm is set to 7:00 the app should set the alarm 30 minutes back to 6:30.
I know about AlarmProvider which is used in the stock Android clock app but I have no idea how to change an already set alarm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should help you access the already set alarm times.

https://code.google.com/p/android-alarm-database/

Just have a look at https://code.google.com/p/android-alarm-database/source/browse/trunk/src/com/android/alarmclock/util/AlarmDatabase.java

With this you should be easily be able to figure out how to access everything you need.